# in VIM, How to set the initial window size via file browser?

Tags: vim

I'm using vim to browse through different folders. (i.e., issue :tabe . command in vim)

However, when I open the file either in split window (pressing 'o') or in vertical split window(pressing 'v'), the newly opened window size is really small. (while meanwhile, vim's file browser's windows stays pretty big which I don't really need).

I know that I can manually change the window size by Ctrl+W with either -/+ or split, or  for vertical split, or '=' to make the window sizes equal; but that's too troublesome.

I want to check if there're existing ways to set the default size of the window opened using "o" or "v" to be bigger?

Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: "Lex" + "vertical resize" did the job for me: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/10988/toggle-explorer-window/26029#26029

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The new window should take half of the height or half of the width of the current window which can give you small windows pretty quickly.

The option that defines that proportion can be found in `:help netrw`:

```
let g:netrw_winsize = 75
```

Note that using this method will make any further split even smaller than before:

```
let g:netrw_winsize = 50 (default)
|-netrw--------------------------------------------|
|-netrw------------------|-file--------------------|
|-netrw------|-file------|-file--------------------|

let g:netrw_winsize = 75
|-netrw--------------------------------------------|
|-netrw------|-file--------------------------------|
|-netrw|-file|-file--------------------------------|
```

The "problem", here is that netrw splits its own window, not the previous window.

Netrw can be used to open the file under the cursor in the current window, in a split window or in another tab but the way it splits its own window makes it hard to use it the way you want. AFAIK, the most common usage is:

1. open netrw with `:Ex`,
2. navigate,
3. hit `<CR>` to open the file under the cursor in the current window,
4. edit,
5. re-open netrw *in its latest state* with `:Rex` (for Peter Rincker),
6. `GOTO 2`

An alternative is to use `:Vex` to open netrw in a vertical split and use `P` to open the file in the *previous* window.

I'm afraid Netrw is not really designed to work like what you seem to want it to work. IMO, netrw is more like an "open…" dialog than the kind of file explorer pane you can see in most editors/IDEs. I'd suggest you either get used to it or try [NERDTree](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658) which has only a subset of netrw's features but is designed to be more like those file explorer panes.

Comment: +1 Please mention `:Rex` as an alternative workflow. I believe learned about this wonderful command form you.

Comment: @PeterRincker, answer modified. `:Rex` is key.

Comment: I would up vote you again for an explanation with a `goto` in it.

Comment: What is `:Rex`? I am getting `Not an editor command: Rex`.

Comment: @JoyceBabu then a) you are not using Vim, or b) you are using a seriously stripped down Vim, or c) your Vim was installed incorrectly. See `:help :Rexplore`.

Comment: I am getting the same error on  `Vim 8.2.5032` included with macOs, `Vim 9.0.300` installed with homebrew, `Neovim v0.7.2` installed with homebrew.

Comment: I couldn't find it on `Vim 8.2.3995` from official repo on `Pop OS 22.04` too.

Comment: @JoyceBabu Are you following the instructions provided in the answer or typing random commands? It says to do `:Ex`, *then* open a file, *then* do `:Rex`.

Comment: Yes. I just realized the mistake, after running `:h :Rexplore` as you suggested. The `:Rex` command works, after opening a `netrw` buffer with  one of the `:*explore` commands

Answer (score 6):

Actually the split size is not relative to netrw, it's the default size vim sets for newly created splits, so if you want to resize the actual split which is in you case the navigator (netrw) you can use this commend:

```
:vertical resize 30
```

Answer (score 3):

There is `:Lex` now to open a left explorer. You can place `let g:netrw_winsize=30` in your *vimrc* file to keep the explorer small.

Comment: I was opening left panel with `Vexplore` then resizing, this helped.

Comment: Only problem with `g:netrw_winsize` is that it gets applied differently depending on what you do. Select a file and `p`: you get netrw taking up 30% of the space it occupied; use `P` (or `o` or `v`) instead and the file takes up 30%, instead, which is not what you want.